# php bcpowmod returns floating point

Tags: php, bcmath

When using bcpowmod, I sometimes get back a string with a floating point value in it.  It only does this sometimes when running the function through WAMP server.  Other times, it works as expected, even with the same parameters.  If I run the same code from the command line, it always seems to work correctly.  If I use bcpow() and bcmod() separately, it works fine all the time.

For example:

```
bcpowmod('378', '2', '4294967291') => '0.3166531993' or '142884'
bcmod(bcpow('378', '2'), '4294967291') => '142884'
```

I'm using php 7.0.0 on Apache 2.4.17.  Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

Comment: what is the wamp version? is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: 64bit Wamp 3.0.0